# How to cast NSObject to other type in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I have a method which returns `NSObject` like this

```
[BindingImpl (BindingImplOptions.GeneratedCode | BindingImplOptions.Optimizable)]
    public virtual NSObject AgentHandler {
        [Export ("agentHandler")]
        get {
            NSObject ret;
            if (IsDirectBinding) {
                ret = Runtime.GetNSObject (global::ApiDefinitions.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("agentHandler")));
            } else {
                ret = Runtime.GetNSObject (global::ApiDefinitions.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (this.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle ("agentHandler")));
            }
            return ret;
        }

    }
```

Then I have a `NSObject` type class

```
public unsafe abstract partial class LSMAHandler : NSObject
```

I want to cast my `NSObject` to `LSMAHandler`
is it possible?

I did something like this

```
NSObject handler = lSUniversal.AgentHandler;
var myHandler = (LSMAHandler)handler;
```

But this gives me an error

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. occurred

**UPDATE**

```
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSObject<LSMAHandler,LSMAHandlerPincode,LSMAHandlerRegister> *agentHandler;
```

This is my objective c property. I want to define this in my `ApiDefinition.cs`

**UPDATE 2**

```
 [BaseType(typeof(LSMAHandler))]
 [Protocol, Model]
 interface LSMAHandlerRegister

[Protocol, Model]
interface LSMAHandlerPincode : LSMAHandler
```

Comment: What's the original type of `lSUniversal.AgentHandler`? You can't cast any other type to `LSMAHandler`.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT I have updated the question. Please see the UPDATED part.

Comment: C# doesn't support multiple inheritances. I've seen `LSMAHandler` is an abstract class and what's the type of `LSMAHandlerPincode` and `LSMAHandlerRegister`?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT Please see the UPDATE 2 part of my question

Answer (score 0):

Define a class like:

```
public class AgentHandler : LSMAHandler, LSMAHandlerPincode, LSMAHandlerRegister
{
}
```

Then your property could be like this:

```
public AgentHandler agentHandler;
```

Comment: How to define this in ApiDefinition.cs?

Comment: @Randi It seems you have defined the AgentHandler class in your code above. Why do you want to cast your `AgentHandler` to `LSMAHandler`? If `AgentHandler` is inherited from `LSMAHandler`, it contains the parent class's methods and properties. Just consume that class directly.

Comment: [yourSDKPointer.agentHandler registerWithURL:<#The registration URL#> 
                                    andReference:<#The reference to be used when sending notification#>
                                    onSignIn:^(LSMARegistrationStatus_t statusCode, RegistrationError_t status){
  if (statusCode == LSMARegistrationStatus_registered) {
    NSLog(@"Registration successful!");
  }
}]; This is the way native objective c has called. RegisterWithURL is a method inside the LSMAHandlerRegister. in native it called through the agentHandler object. I am trying to do the same thing in here

Comment: @Randi Cast your agentHandler to `AgentHandler`. Try to debug what the original type of `lSUniversal.AgentHandler` is.

Comment: Since I have defined it as NSObject in my ApiDefinition.cs, AgentHandler is NSObject type

Comment: @Randi I haven't used this library before. Why not define it as a certain property as you want?